# Storing GeoCoordinate in a PCL file used by a UWP - Win 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I need to store geo coordinates in my POCO object which is contained in a Portable Class Library. It compiles fine but when I include my PCL file in my UWP project, it generates over 15,000 exceptions.

If I remove the GeoCoordinate property from my PCL file, compiling the UWP project which has the reference to the PCL file compiles ok.

The property is defined as follows:

```
public GeoCoordinate {get; set;}
```

Any ideas?

Is there another way to use store geo coordinates without using the `Windows.Devices.GeoLocation` reference which I has to add to my class in the PCL project?

Comment: Can you please select several exceptions and post here so can we have an analysis? And `public GeoCoordinate {get; set;}`, is the `GeoCoordinate` here the class of `GeoLocation` namespace used for data type, or is this your property name and missed a data type here?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT The GeoCoordinate is the class from 'using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;. I'll post a few errors as an update to my question.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Very strange. I went to uncomment my property to get the errors, but noticed that everything is now compiling as expected! I have no idea as to how it got resolved as I haven't rebooted my PC or installed any patches! Glad the error is gone but pain it couldn't be reproduced.